# Move file in git without move

Tags: git

A script I need to execute moves a few hundred files in my repository from one location to another (but they stay in the repo). I know where the files came from, and where they are after the ove.

But `git mv` wants to move the files on its own. Is there any way to use `git mv` telling it that the move operation was already done?

Comment: You could `git add path/to/old/dir` to register the deletion and `git add path/to/new/dir` to register the new location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git will automatically identify moves on its own even if you don't use `git mv`, as long as you stage both the deleted and the new file.

In fact, Git uses only the contents of files to sort out what is a move. Therefore, `git mv` is just a shorthand for the above.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Can I circumvent the "auto detection" by invoking these commands manually as well?

Comment: Btw, is there a overview which commands is a composition of other commands?

Comment: @DanielStephens What do you mean? Git basically stored files deleted and files added, and if something is roughly similar, then it claims it is a move. There is no way (at least things have changed) to disable or change how that works.

Comment: @DanielStephens As for the second question, I would suggest reading the Git book!

Comment: :"then it claims it is a move" But this is an auto-detection, correct? As far as I know it makes the 85% compare contents detection. I was hoping for this "condition" could be triggered differently

Comment: @DanielStephens Yeah, it is (unless things have changed recently; I haven't looked into the details since a few years ago).